# MA, PFA and selective ultrafilters.

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, filters

I have two questions:

1. Anybody knows where can I find a proof of $\text{MA}\to\exists p\in\mathbb{N}^\ast\text{ selective (Ramsey)}$?
2. It is known if $\text{PFA}\to\exists p\in\mathbb{N}^\ast\text{ selective (Ramsey)}$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a proof that there is a Ramsey ultrafilter assuming MA, see Theorem 6.11 of [these notes](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~shac/forcing/forcing2014.pdf). Meanwhile, since PFA implies MA, PFA certainly implies that there is a Ramsey ultrafilter.

---

The proof that PFA implies MA amounts to showing that c.c.c. forcings are proper; this is a nice argument, so I'll sketch it here.

EDIT: As Andreas points out below, PFA is often (usually?) stated in the form "If $\mathbb{P}$ is proper and $\mathcal{D}$ is a collection of $\aleph_1$-many dense sets, then there is a $\mathcal{D}$-generic filter." If we adopt this version, then the argument is much harder: we need to show that this form of PFA implies $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2$, which is harder than it sounds. I'm using the seemingly-stronger form of PFA, which says we can meet fewer-than-continuum-many dense sets in a proper forcing and that $2^{\aleph_0}>\aleph_1$, which is how it was taught to me.

Also, I'm using the definition of "properness" in terms of elementary submodels rather than stationarity preserving, since I find it more intuitive.

Recall that $\mathbb{P}$ is proper if for all countable $M\prec H_\theta$ with $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{P})\in H_\theta$, and all $q\in \mathbb{P}\cap M$, there is some $q'\le q$ such that whenever $r\le q'$ and $D\subseteq \mathbb{P}$ is dense and $D\in M$, there is an $s\in D\cap M$ compatible with $r$. (Such a $q'$ is called *$(\mathbb{P}, M)$-generic*.)

I claim that the trivial condition $\mathbb{1}$ in a c.c.c. forcing is $(\mathbb{P}, M)$-generic. Why? Well, let $r\in\mathbb{P}$ and $D\subseteq\mathbb{P}$ be dense with $D\in M$. Without loss of generality, $D=\{p: \exists a\in A(p\le a)\}$ for some maximal antichain $A$ with $A\in M$ (why?).

Since $\mathbb{P}$ is c.c.c., we have that $A$ is countable. But now we use the following neat fact:

> If $X\in M\prec H(\theta)$ with $\theta$ infinite and $X$ is countable, then $X\subseteq M$.

*Hint for proof: by elementarity $M$ thinks $X$ is countable too, so $M$ thinks $f$ is an injection of $A$ into $\mathbb{N}$ for some $f\in M$...*

So $A\subseteq M$. Since $D$ is dense, there is some $s\le r$ with $s\in D$. By definition of $A$, we have $s\le a$ for some $a\in A$, and since $D\supseteq A\subseteq M$ we have $a\in D\cap M$. So we're done.

Comment: Note that a useful consequence of the neat fact mentioned is that $M\cap \omega_1\in \omega_1$.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know about some proof of $\text{PFA}\to\text{ there exists selective ultrafilters}$ that doesn't go through Martin's Axiom?

Comment: @DanielCalderón No, I don't, and I don't believe one exists. (Also, note that the proof from MA really requires *continuum many* applications of MA.)

Comment: I can't see how the proof use $\text{MA}$ more than once as the meat of the construction is in $\mathfrak{t}=2^\omega$ what is just a consequence of $\text{MA}$. Can you please tell me why this make you believe that there is no a direct construction using $\text{PFA}$?

Comment: The proof that PFA implies MA needs another ingredient, because MA (in the form needed to produce a selective ultrafilter) is stated in terms of generic filters meeting any $<2^{\aleph_0}$ dense sets, while PFA is usually stated in terms of meeting $\aleph_1$ dense sets. So to get from (this form of) PFA to MA, one needs the (nontrivial) fact that PFA implies $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Good point - I was taking PFA as stating that you could meet any $<2^{\aleph_0}$-many dense sets in a proper forcing, which is how it was presented to me.

Comment: @DanielCalderón The two facts I mention are unrelated; the only reason I think there isn't a more direct construction via PFA is that I've never seen one. As to the uses of MA bit, if you think of constructing a Ramsey ultrafilter in stages, at each stage $\kappa<2^\omega$ you apply MA to extend your tower by one more set (essentially, showing "$\mathfrak{t}>\kappa$" for a fixed $\kappa<2^\omega$ takes one use of MA). You don't have to think about it this way, but it can be made precise and winds up being kind of interesting.

Comment: @NoahSchweber If it were up to me, that might be how I'd formulate PFA (as well as MA), but it would have the unexpected consequence that CH would imply PFA.  This would require rewriting the hypotheses of a lot of theorems to say "PFA and not CH" rather than just PFA.

Comment: @AndreasBlass That's a nice point. I've edited to make that clear. (I was actually introduced to PFA as including $\neg$CH, which I forgot to include above.)

Comment: I'd like to point out that, in light of the fact that countably closed forcings (and hence, say, the forcing to collapse $\omega_2$ to $\omega_1$) are proper, the idea of a PFA for $< 2^{\aleph_0}$-many dense sets is very confusing.  Of course it's not so confusing any more once you know that PFA (for just $\aleph_1$-many dense sets) implies $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_2$.